# How to make two breeds of turtles alternate when coming out of the same nest

Tags: netlogo

In this ant model, I have two breeds of turtles: minors and foragers. Right now all of the foragers will come out single file followed by all of the minors (this is done by delaying initial departure. I want them to take turns when coming out until I either run out of foragers or run out of minors.

I have tried putting ask turtles [if who >= ticks [ stop ]] as the first step in the GO procedure, but that made all of the turtles explode out of the nest instead of leaving single file.

```
to go 
  ask foragers
  [ if who >= ticks [ stop ]  ;; delay initial departure
    wiggle
    fd 1 ]
  ask minors
  [ if who >= ticks [ stop ]  ;; delay initial departure
    ifelse color = white
    [ look-for-transporter ]
    [ hitchhike ]]
  tick
end
```

I want foragers and minors to alternate when leaving the nest. Right now all of the foragers leave before the minors do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`who` numbers are assigned to each **turtle** as it is created and is independent of breed. So, if you create 10 foragers and then create 10 minors, your foragers will have `who` values from 0 to 9, and your minors will have `who` values from 10 to 19. For this reason, whichever breed you create first (and therefore has the lowest range of `who` numbers) will start to move according to your `if who >= ticks...` code. To get your `who` based code to do what you need, you'd have to alternate your creation of your foragers and minors.

However, in general using `who` numbers is a little restrictive- you may find it easier to make your own variables or control this some other way. For example, the setup below creates a `nest-patch` at the far left of the world and moves some foragers and minors to that patch. The turtles have a boolean variable called `at-nest?` which you can use to control which turtles can move:

```
breed [ foragers forager ]
breed [ minors minor ]

globals [ last-left nest-patch ]
turtles-own [ at-nest? ]

to setup
  ca
  create-foragers 10 [ set color red ]
  create-minors 20 [ set color blue ]
  set nest-patch patch min-pxcor 0
  ask nest-patch [ set pcolor yellow ]
  ask turtles [
    move-to nest-patch
    set heading 90
    set at-nest? true
    pd
  ]
  set last-left minors
  reset-ticks
end
```

Initially, all turtles have their `at-nest?` set to true. You can then alternate between individuals of each breed that you ask to set their `at-nest?` to `true`. Have a look at the example below, which has some more detail in comments:

```
to go
  ; If there are any turtles on the nest patch with at-nest? set to true
  if any? ( turtles-on nest-patch ) with [ at-nest? ] [
    ; If both breeds are present on the nest patch, alternate back and forth
    ; between breeds to set at-nest? to false
    ifelse ( length remove-duplicates [breed] of turtles-on nest-patch = 2 ) [
      set last-left ifelse-value ( last-left = minors ) [ foragers ] [ minors ]
      ask one-of last-left with [ at-nest? ] [
        set at-nest? false
      ]
    ] [
      ; Otherwise, just ask one-of whichever breed is left to set at-nest? to false
      ask one-of turtles-on nest-patch [
        set at-nest? false
      ]   
    ]
  ]

  ; Ask any turtles who have at-nest? set to false to move
  ask turtles with [ not at-nest? ] [
    if heading != 90 [
      rt ifelse-value ( breed = minors ) [ 12 ] [ -12 ]
    ]
    if xcor > 0 and heading = 90 [
      rt ifelse-value ( breed = minors ) [ 12 ] [ -12 ]
    ]
    fd 1
  ]      
  tick
end
```

That code outputs something like:

[image]